# creating soft links with the same name as the target file

Tags: shell, awk, filenames, symlink, hardlink

```
ln -s /dir1/file1   /dir2/file1
```

I'd like to create a softlink in target dir1  with same filename as source in dir2
How is this done without typing the file1 name over in the target path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `ln`-only options:

```
ln -s -t /dir1 /dir2/file1
```

Comment: so I assume I can also do this right `ls -s -t /d1 /d2/*` tyvm

Comment: I ended up using this one `cp -rs /dir/<search pattern> /dest1`

Answer (score 8):

It is very frustrating typing the name over and over again if you're creating several symlinks. Here's how I bypass retyping the name in Linux.

Here's my example file structure:

```
source/
 - file1.txt
 - file2.js
 - file3.js
target/
```

#### Create symlink to single file

`~$ ln -sr source/file2.js target/`

Result:

```
source/
 - file1.txt
 - file2.js
 - file3.js
target/
 - file2.js
```

#### Create symlink to all files with matching extension in `source`

`~$ ln -sr source/*.js target/`

Result:

```
source/
 - file1.txt
 - file2.js
 - file3.js
target/
 - file2.js
 - file3.js
```

#### Create symlinks to all files in `source`

`~$ ln -sr source/* target/`

Result:

```
source/
 - file1.txt
 - file2.js
 - file3.js
target/
 - file1.txt
 - file2.js
 - file3.js
```

---

### Relativity

Notice the `r` option. If you don't include `-r` the link source must be entered relative to the link location.

- `~$ ln -s ../source/file1.txt target/` Works
- `~/target$ ln -s ../source/file1.txt .` Works
- `~$ ln -s source/file1.txt target/` Does not work

See also:

[How to create symbolic links to all files (class of files) in a directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/633605/how-to-create-symbolic-links-to-all-files-class-of-files-in-a-directory)

[Linux man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html)